# HighCharts: getting access to calculated spline 'points'

Tags: highcharts

I'm using the built-in spline curve fit to an x-y plot.  Is there a way of getting access to the splined data that HighCharts itself is plotting?  I (obviously) have access to my supplied x,y co-ordinates but I'd like access to the HighCharts-calculated spline intermediate values.

Take http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols as an example.  The raw data is (month,temperature) and the closest point to the mouse get displayed as a tooltip.  I'm interested in displaying the *intermediate* 'points' so that as I move my mouse along a line it displays the calculated spline values.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been dormant for a while but I did manage to figure out a way of doing it.  See also a related follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62251625/highcharts-set-an-id-for-a-spline-data-set).

Say you want to find a 'y' value for a given 'x' on a HighCharts generated spline. If you can get at the SVG `path` for that spline then you can walk it's length until you hit the required 'x'.  Then read off the required 'y'.

This fiddle gives an example: https://jsfiddle.net/r3f2xL6b/1/