# HighCharts: set an id for a spline data set?

Tags: javascript, dom, highcharts

I'm creating a HighCharts spline chart with multiple data sets.  It all works fine...

Now I want to get at the `<path>` element for each curve so I can use SVG functions like path.getTotalLength()

Can I set an id or something in the JSON data that will appear in the `<path>` so I can get to it via document.getElementById(id) or a similar *unambiguous* method?

**Here what I've tried:** I know can set a 'className' in my JSON and that className will appear in the `<g>` parent node of the `<path>` (and in other places too, eg legend).  So I can get to the desired `<path>` that way but it looks a bit too hacky and fragile. An unambiguous id would be nicer.

**Here's why I'm trying to do this:**
I want my user to be able to enter an 'x' value and get returned the 'y' value of each spline in the chart at the entered 'x'.  The only way I can find to do this is to 'walk' the length of the spline curve (obtained from mypath.getTotalLength()) and use the SVG function mypath.getPointAtLength(some length) until I reach the desired 'x' value.  If there's a better way to do this with a spline I'd like to know!

Comment: Hi @SAL, There is only one path element for a whole series, so you will not be able to add id for every curve. You need to calculate the required value in a different way. Please check similar thread here: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=36066 You can also check spline source code: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/parts/SplineSeries.ts

Comment: @ppotaczek.  I thought about having a 'shadow' spline from which I could access the calculated data.  But I figured that HighCharts had already done the hard maths! I came up with a solution to my "Give me an 'x' and I'll give you a 'y'" problem- see https://jsfiddle.net/r3f2xL6b/1/